# Insert into sql server table, using subquery returning more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables

**table1**

[image]

**table2**

[image]

**table3**

[image]

I want for every id in table2 where condition is true, to insert 2 rows in table1. The rows should have the table2.id and table3.id ( for all ids in table3)

Here is my script so far.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (wid, w_check_id)
SELECT (SELECT w.id FROM table2 w WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE w.category_code IN ('004','001')),
       id
FROM table3 WITH(NOLOCK)
```

The expected result should be something like this:

table1

**id   |  w_id   | w_check_id**

1      | 32098   | 1

2      | 32098   | 2

3      | 82459   | 1

4      | 82459   | 2

Comment: Specify the expected result as well. As formatted text, not images!

Comment: Do you know why you are using `NOLOCK` or are you just using it?

Comment: @Leonidas199x I guess it's some kind of habit.

Comment: @K.Krunk so long as you know what it is actually doing, and don't fall into the thinking of 'No lock means it doesn't lock' then you're good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`The rows should have the table2.id and all ids in table3` sounds like you need a cross join as:

```
Insert into  @T1 (wid,w_check_id)
SELECT w.id,T3.Id
FROM @T2 w 
cross JOin @T3 T3
WHERE w.wallet_category_code IN ('004','001')
```